# cs50 pset5 speller - loop runs forever AND 'words in dictionary' frozen at first value

Tags: c, dictionary, cs50

Would love some help with the fifth pset - (speller - https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/5/speller/) of Harvard's cs50 2020 course . I'm facing 2 issues:

1. **Program takes AGES to run with dictionaries longer than ~100 words**. I left it running for 30 mins and it still did not finish. I don't know why this is happening - would appreciate any insights
2. **Once a dictionary has been loaded into the program the output "WORDS IN DICTIONARY" does not update, even if I add more words to the dictionary file in question.** e.g. the dictionary 'small' initially had 2 words in it, I added a third but WORDS IN DICTIONARY continuously outputs a 2. Even when I save as, as a new file that doesn't change things. Again no idea why this is happening would appreciate help!

   ```
   #include <stdbool.h>
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <string.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <strings.h>
   #include <ctype.h>
   #include "dictionary.h"

   // Represents a node in a hash table
   typedef struct node
   {
       char word[LENGTH + 1];
       struct node *next;
   }
   node;

   // Number of buckets in hash table
   const unsigned int N = 60; // set hash table to number of letters

   // Counter for number of words loaded into dictionary
   int counter = 0;

   // Hash table
   node *table[N];

   // Returns true if word is in dictionary else false
   bool check(const char *word)
   {
       // TODO

       // Find index that word would be placed in dictionary table if it exsits
       unsigned int y = hash(word);
       int result = 0;
       // If entry at that index is empty then obviously word not in dictionary
       if (table[y] == NULL)
           {
               return false;
           }

       // Otherwise iterate through entire linked list at that index and check if word exists
       else
       {
           for (node *tmp = table[y]; tmp != NULL; tmp = tmp->next)
           {
               result = strcasecmp(word,table[y]->word);
               if (result == 0)
               {
                   return true;
               }
           }
       }
       return false;
   }

   // Hashes word to a number

   unsigned int hash(const char *word)
   {


       // Hash function adapted from djb2 algorithm from following website http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html
       unsigned int hash = 5381;
       int c;
       while ((c = *word++))
           hash += (hash << 5) + (c | 040); /* hash * 33 + c */ // Adaptation to make all lowercase from - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40140390/hash-function-issue-adding-functionality - olegarch comment

       return hash % N;
   }

   // Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
   bool load(const char *dictionary)
   {
       // TODO
       // Open file
       FILE *dict = fopen(dictionary, "r");
       if (dict == NULL)
       {
           return false;
       }

       // Set up temporary variable to hold words
       char entry[LENGTH + 1];

       // Loop over entire file, extract words into temp var, store temp var in node
       do
       {
           // extract single word into entry variable
           fscanf(dict, "%s", entry);

           // create node and store word inside
           node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
           if (n == NULL)
           {
               return false;
           }
           strcpy(n->word,entry);
           n->next = NULL;

           // Hash word into index
           unsigned int x = hash(entry);



           // Loop through linked list at position x in hash table
           if (table[x] == NULL)
           {
               table[x] = n;
           }
           else
           {
               for (node *tmp = table[x]; tmp != NULL; tmp = tmp->next)
               {
                   // Insert new node at start of list
                   n->next = table[x];
                   table[x] = n;
               }
           }
           counter++; // Update dictionary word counter

          // clear memory allocation from n
         // free(n);


       }
       while (fscanf(dict,"%s", entry) != EOF);

       fclose(dict);
       return true;


   }

   // Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded
   unsigned int size(void)
   {
       // TODO
       // if hash table = null, return 0
       // looks through hash table and counts elements

       return counter;
   }

   // Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful else false
   bool unload(void)
   {
       // TODO
       // deletes words from dictionary one at a time
       int deleted = 0;

       // Iterate over every index position in table
       for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
       {
           while (table[i] != NULL) // enter if index has a non-blank list and delete all entries back to front
           {
               node *del = table[i]->next;
               free(table[i]);
               table[i] = del;
               deleted++;
           }
       }

       // Checks if all words have been deleted
       if (deleted == counter)
       {
           return true;
       }
       return false;
   }
   ```

Comment: Note: You're doing a double `fscanf()`, once in the loop body and once in the `while` condition.

Comment: According to your findings, it is likely to be the `load` function. And slowness is possibly because of either loop does not finish and running endlessly, or there are two nested loops that makes the script extremely slow to execute, which might be the case here because I see `for loop` inside `do while`.

Comment: @vmt re doing a double fscanf() - this was the only way I could think of to loop reading the file until the end - what are the disadvantages of doing this and do you have any suggestions for a better method? Thank you!

Comment: @earik87 - I used a do loop to spellcheck every word in a given file, the do loop selects the right index for the hash table and then I used a for loop to iterate over any linked lists at the 'right' index to look for the word in question. Do you have any suggestions for a better method? Thank you!